# TIBCO BW 6.2 remote TEA server deployment

Tags: tibco, businessworks, tibco-business-works

In TIBCO BW 6.2, is it possible to deploy the application to the remote TEA server using bwadmin or maven?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can deploy the application over any that is available in your bwagent network. Here, in BW 6x, you do not need to worry about the tea server. TEA is not at all need in case of deployment through bwadmin (plz do not compare classic admin/BW5x & TEA/BW6x). In classic deployment happen through administrator but in BW6x environment deployment happened via TEA or BWadmin shell.

When you try to deploy application through bwadmin in that case TEA will not come in picture. You can deploy your application using bwadmin
ex. bwadmin -f cmd/AppManage_deploy.cmd

write your deployment commands in .cmd file

refer to TIBCO Administration -> core Admin scripts for more details.

In short, TEA do not have direct dependency over your deployment when you do it through bwadmin.

Answer (score 2):

Developer want to deploy an application In TIBCO BW 6.X,I recommend using bwadmin.

bwadmin provides a command line console that can be used in local mode or enterprise mode to create and manage domains, AppSpaces, AppNodes, archives, and applications.

For example,execute the following command from the command line to deploy an uploaded application archive to TestAppSpace

```
BW_HOME\bin>bwadmin deploy -d TestDomain -a TestAppSpace TestExample.application_1.0.0.ear
```